# Extracting characters from string

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

The dataset structure is:

```
> str(trainData)
'data.frame':   891 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ PassengerId: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Survived   : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Pclass     : Factor w/ 3 levels "1st","2nd","3rd": 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ Name       : chr  "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris" "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)" "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina" "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)" ...
 $ Sex        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Male","Female": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Age        : num  22 38 26 35 35 NA 54 2 27 14 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ Ticket     : int  NA NA NA 113803 373450 330877 17463 349909 347742 237736 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
 $ Cabin      : chr  "" "C85" "" "C123" ...
 $ Embarked   : chr  "S" "C" "S" "S" ...
 $ Area       : Factor w/ 9 levels "","A","B","C",..: 1 4 1 4 1 1 6 1 1 1 ...
```

I want to create a new column in the data frame to store the form of address contained in the Name variable. To do so, I need to extract the strings "Mr", "Mrs", etc.. and store them in a new vector. I thought to address the problem in the following way.

```
vec <- vector()

for (i in 1 : nrow(trainData)) {
  if (grep("Mr\\.", trainData[i, "Name"]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Mr"}
  else if (grep("Miss\\.", trainData[i, "Name"]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Miss"}
  else if (grep("Mrs\\.", trainData[i, "Name"]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Mrs"}
  else if (grep("Don\\.", trainData[i, "Name"]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Don"}
  else if (grep("Master\\.", trainData[i, "Name"]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Master"}
  else {vec[i] <- "Boh"}
}
```

.. and after that use the `cbind` function to bind the existent data frame with the new column 
`FormOfAddress`. I didn't test the next two lines of code, because I get an error message from the previous chunk.

```
trainData <- as.data.frame(cbind(trainData, vec))
names(trainData)[length(trainData)] <- "FormOfAddress"
```

Basically I got stuck at this point..

```
> vec <- vector()
> for (i in 1 : nrow(trainData)) {
+ if (grep("Mr\\.", trainData[i, c("Name")]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Mr"}
+ else if (grep("Miss\\.", trainData[i, c("Name")]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Miss"}
+ else if (grep("Mrs\\.", trainData[i, c("Name")]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Mrs"}
+ else if (grep("Don\\.", trainData[i, c("Name")]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Don"}
+ else if (grep("Master\\.", trainData[i, c("Name")]) == 1) {vec[i] <- "Master"}
+ else {vec[i] <- "Boh"; next}
+ }
Error in if (grep("Mr\\.", trainData[i, c("Name")]) == 1) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

The first part of the if statement looks right to me. When the string `Mr.` is contained in the Name, it returns `TRUE`. Also the second part looks fine (at least on the first loop) and write the string `Mr` on the vector `vec`.
The problem is on the second loop I think, but I cannot find a way to make it work.

Comment: You want `grepl` if you want to return a logical. `grep` returns the indices of matches, so if there's no match the result of `grep` will be a length 0 vector. Look at `?gsub` for an easier way to do this without a for loop

Comment: Thank you Jake, `grepl` works fine. I will have a look at `gsub` tomorrow to see how to address the issue without using a for loop statement.

Comment: I added an answer with a `gsub` solution. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
trainData$Name

## [1] "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris"                            
## [2] "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)"
## [3] "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"                             
## [4] "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)"       
## [5] "tt"                                                 
## [6] "Mr. Jones"                                          

for (x in trainData$Name) {
    print(grep("Mr\\.", x))
    print(grepl("Mr\\.", x));
}

## [1] 1
## [1] TRUE
## integer(0)
## [1] FALSE
## integer(0)
## [1] FALSE
## integer(0)
## [1] FALSE
## integer(0)
## [1] FALSE
## [1] 1
## [1] TRUE

## Doing it without a loop.
## You might have to come up with a different
## regex here depending on the rest of your data
vec <- gsub("^([^,]+, )?([^.]+).*", "\\2", trainData$Name)
## [1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "tt"   "Mr"  
vec <- ifelse(vec == trainData$Name, "Boh", vec)
## [1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Miss" "Mrs"  "Boh"  "Mr"
```